# Openstack on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS what is the suitable branch

Tags: openstack, ubuntu-18.04, devstack

Can anyone help me to find the suitable openstack branch to install it on the ubuntu 18.04 LTS or any tutorial to help me. I tryied to install the pike and Queens branch but I found that they are only supported on xenial.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install Rocky on Ubuntu 18.04, but it looks like it may not yet be available from Cloud Archives.

If you are looking at developing simply installing the master branch of devstack should get you going.

Following the instructions here should help get you started.

> https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

You can easily install Rocky the same way using devstack.